# I want to hide user's name and age when page is open

Tags: javascript, function, visibility

I have a radio button which is yes and no. If user chooses yes then it displays user's name and age, if selected no then it wouldn't not display name or age. This works fine but when the page is open, obviously none of the two radio buttons are selected but the name and age is visible, so what I want to know is how by default when the page is open do I code it so that the user's name and age is hidden rather than visible?

```
function getMsg() {
                var choice = document.getElementsByName("choice");               
                var userName = document.getElementById("userName");
                var userAge = document.getElementById("userAge");

                if(choice[0].checked == true){
                    userName.style.visibility = "visible";
                    userAge.style.visibility = "visible";

                }else{
                    userName.style.visibility = "hidden";
                    userAge.style.visibility = "hidden";
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

In the elements you want to start as hidden, use `style="visibility:hidden;"`.

Comment: I tried that and it is not hiding it, thats why I am suprised with this

Answer (score 0):

please use `style="display:none"` and see if that work. If not try with jQuery `$("#userName").hide();`. Good luck!